# Maintain state of checkboxlist inside gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist(with 4 listitems) in one of the columns of the gridview.It is not populated from database.I want to maintain the state of all the listitems(checked or unchecked) when I navigate to another page of the gridview.I have tried setting `EnableViewstate="true"` for the gridview and checkboxlist but it doesnt work. Here's the html mark-up:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUnits" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnRowDataBound="grdUnit_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="grdUnit_PageIndexChanging" 
                        RowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightBlue"  BorderStyle="Solid"
                        Height="426px" Width="1500px">
                        <PagerSettings  Mode="Numeric" />
                        <Columns>
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="SUKEY" HeaderText="Unit Code" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="CREDITS" HeaderText="Credits"/> 
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <HeaderTemplate>Standard Semester or Term</HeaderTemplate>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblStandardSem" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Left" RepeatLayout="Table">
                                         <asp:ListItem Value="SummerTermSemSt" Text="14ST"></asp:ListItem>
                                         <asp:ListItem Value="Semester1St" Text="14S1"></asp:ListItem>
                                         <asp:ListItem Value="WinterTermSemSt" Text="14WT"></asp:ListItem>
                                         <asp:ListItem Value="Semester2St" Text="14S2"></asp:ListItem>
                                     </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"/>
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
          BindDataGrid();
    }
}

private void BindDataGrid()
{
    //fetch data from database
    grdUnits.DataBind();
}

protected void grdUnit_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
     grdUnits.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     BindDataGrid();
}
```

I have come across posts that mention about maintaining state for a checkboxlist outside a gridvew but that isnt helpful. I am unable to figure out a way for maintaining the state of the checkboxlist(which is inside a gridview) and saving it to the database.

Comment: see this 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/04/maintaining-state-of-checkboxes-while.html

Comment: @AmitKumar: I read this post but since it is for checkbox,it doesnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you set the `EnableViewstate="true"` or not, when your control (CheckBoxList) is not populating or its not checking from a database your control will lose the checked data at any time you call the grid-view DataBind method.

The only way that I could think of is keep the control data in a Session variable but this is going to be insane if you have hundreds of records in your grid-view. and you don't wanna make your server slow definitely.

So I strongly recommend to handle the state via database if you have a large number of records on your grid-view.

Comment: I would write to database eventually,but I want to maintain state while paging gridview.Lets say the user selects a few items in a few rows on the 1st page,jumps to the 4th page...selects some more items and then goes back to the 1st page.I want to restore the values selected.

Comment: I know what exactly you are trying to do, as I said this is doable using session variables so you just need to set your control values to the session within the `grdUnit_PageIndexChanging` event. and use it in the same event as well.